# Why DataGridView CellBeginEdit event is triggered twice on first click?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm fetching a list of records in DataGridView having a checkbox in it. I'm using **CellBeginEdit** to send data when the checkbox is clicked. On form load, if no checkbox is selected and, I select the first checkbox or the first checkbox is already checked it works fine it sends data from the first row but if  I select any other checkbox rather than the first one then **CellBeginEdit** is triggered twice and it sends data from the first row on the first trigger, and then sends data from the selected row. I'm unable to find the problem.

Here you can find the form image for clarity [image]

Here is the **ListUsers_CellBeginEdit** that is called on the checkbox click.

```
private void ListUsers_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null && ListUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Here is the DataGridView designer code

```
 // 
        // ListUsers
        // 
        this.ListUsers.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ListUsers.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.ListUsers.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.chkUsers,
        this.columnHeader17,
        this.columnHeader18});
        this.ListUsers.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1, -1);
        this.ListUsers.MultiSelect = false;
        this.ListUsers.Name = "ListUsers";
        this.ListUsers.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(598, 425);
        this.ListUsers.TabIndex = 0;
        this.ListUsers.CellBeginEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(this.ListUsers_CellBeginEdit);
        this.ListUsers.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.ListUsers_CellEndEdit);
        this.ListUsers.EditingControlShowing += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(this.ListUsers_EditingControlShowing);
```

I'm unable to find the problem. Anyone who can help?

Comment: What makes you think the event is firing twice? Have you traced the code to verify this? The posted code does not reproduce what you describe. What is the code doing in the event?

Comment: `CellBeginEdit` is raised when you simply click on a Cell without changing anything and when you click on another Cell. `CellEndEdit` is raised when you move the current Cell, even if you didn't change anything. So, you always have to check first for what Column the event is raised. -- Why don't you use the `CellValueChanged` event instead? (still checking it's a Cell of the *right Column*)

Comment: @Jimi Issue is resolved by moving the call to CellValueChanged. Thanks